# Python Hanging Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I have the following code:

```
    final = []
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.number_threads) as executor:
        _futures = [executor.submit(self.get_attribute, listing,
                                    self.proxies[listings.index(listing) % len(self.proxies)]) for listing
                    in listings]
        for result in futures.as_completed(_futures):
            try:
                listing = result.result()
                final.append(listing)
            except Exception as e:
                print traceback.format_exc()
    return final
```

The self.get_attribute function that's submitted to the executor takes a  dictionary and proxy as input and makes either one or two http requests to get some data and return with an edited dictionary.  The problem is that the workers/threads hang towards the end of completing all the submitted tasks. If I submit 400 dictionaries, it will complete ~380 tasks, and then hang.  If I submit 600, it will complete ~570-580.  However if I submit 25, it will complete all of them.  I'm not sure what the threshold is at which it will go from finishing to not finishing.

I have also tried using a queue and threading system like this:

```
  def _get_attribute_thread(self):
     while self.q.not_empty:
         job = self.q.get()
         listing = job['listing']
         proxy = job['proxy']
         self.threaded_results.put(self.get_attribute(listing, proxy))
         self.q.task_done()

  def _get_attributes_threaded_with_proxies(self, listings):

       for listing in listings:
           self.q.put({'listing': listing, 'proxy': self.proxies[listings.index(listing) % len(self.proxies)]})

       for _ in xrange(self.number_threads):
           thread = threading.Thread(target=self._get_attribute_thread)
           thread.daemon = True
           thread.start()

       self.q.join()

       final = []
       while self.threaded_results.not_empty:
           final.append(self.threaded_results.get())

       return final
```

However the result is the same.  What can I do to fix/debug the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: problem must be: some sites won't respond at all and your pool is full at some point: kind of deadlock. Maybe add a timeout to your queries?